# EF: update referenced objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following situation

```
public static void UpdateUserinfo(int id, Model model)
{
    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        userinfo userinfo = (from u in context.userinfoes where u.Id == id select u).FirstOrDefault();

        userinfo.BirthDate = model.Birthdate;

        var langauges = (from l in context.languages where model.LanguageIDs.Contains((int)l.LanguageID) select l);
        foreach (var l in langauges)
        {
            userinfo.languages.Add(l);

        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When i try to do it like that i get an error:

> {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first."}

So basically i have a table languages and i have table userinfo and an association table userlanguages, so basically in EF you can navigate userinfo.langauges ...

My question how do i update it correctly, how do i add new languages to the userinfo then?

Or should I mabye have something like :

```
userinfo.languages = languages
```

But for that i have to give ICollection, but how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your connection string you should add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` . Once you add this you may iterate over navigation properties on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Use two context objects, like so:

```
public static void UpdateUserinfo(int id, Model model)
{
    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    using (Entities context2 = new Entities())
    {
        userinfo userinfo = (from u in context.userinfoes where u.Id == id select u).FirstOrDefault();

        userinfo.BirthDate = model.Birthdate;

        var langauges = (from l in context2.languages where model.LanguageIDs.Contains((int)l.LanguageID) select l);
        foreach (var l in langauges)
        {
            userinfo.languages.Add(l);

        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really a bad hack as a solution. Using two contexts cause inconsistencies.

Comment: @kkocabiyikv Ah fair enough, I didn't know about the connection string answer you provided, I will leave this here anyway but +1

Comment: I provided the answer after you post it :)